# Alternative to slot="headerCell" in v-data-table Vuetify 2.x

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to upgrade to Vuetify 2.x
So in the older version

```
    <template slot="headerCell" slot-scope="props">
<tableheader :props="props"/> (custom component where I am passing the props so that the header text along with number of row count is displayed) 
</template>
```

I noticed that in the newer vuetify the header cell is not used anymore.

How do I do the same thing with the newer version?
I tried using "headers" but I think I'm doing something wrong as the props is not getting passed properly

If anyone could explain this, it'll be really helpful as I'm new to Vue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two slots `header` and `header.<name>`, the first to customize the whole header and the second one to customize one column with give `<name>` :

```html
<template v-slot:header="props" >
   <tableheader :props="props"/>
</template>
```

or

```html
<template v-slot:header.quantity="props" >
   <tableheader :props="props"/>
</template>
```